# Search C function definition using Compilation Error

Tags: c, function, compilation

I am working on a C project which has same definition of C function in multiple places. I am trying to get the definition of C function using compilation errors like "error: conflicting types for foo_func()"; which also provides header file declaration as "bar_file.h:< line no >: note: previous declaration of foo_func() was here". I want to rely on compilation error instead of grep like commands because compiler knows for sure which function it is linking with, so I can be sure of the function definition which is being used.

I am able to locate the header file with deliberately applying compilation error. Is there a way to use the similar technique to find the definition of function I am using at compilation time?

Example: Let's find the header file which has the declaration of the function we are using. We can end up into the following compilation error by purposeful introduction of multiple definition with a known parameter mismatch.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -c exmpl_01.c -I./
exmpl_01.c:5: error: conflicting types for ‘call_func_other_file’
exmpl_01.h:1: note: previous declaration of ‘call_func_other_file’ was here

$ head -4 exmpl_01.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "exmpl_01.h"
int call_func(void);
int call_func_other_file(char *);

$ cat exmpl_01.h
int call_func_other_file(void);
```

Comment: The error tells you about a conflict between the indicated line of code (should be part of the error message) and the "previous" function declaration (in the indicated header file) - that's all the information you should need to figure out what causes the conflict.

Comment: If you show your actual code (as a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), as well as the complete error message, we can give more targeted advice.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using an IDE which can find the declaration/definition for you? Too practical?

Comment: @Lundin the reason why we don't us IDE is the volume of code quite bigger to be handled with modern IDE.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I did not mean there is definitely a way to find a way by this method. If there is a method using compile error or link error, i would be interested to know. Also if there exists a radically different approach, they are also welcome. I just need to find a the line number and file where the function is am using.

Comment: `grep` to the rescue! ;)

Comment: @MithunB What do yo mean "the volume of code quite bigger to be handled with modern IDE". That sounds like utter nonsense.

Comment: You can try deliberately addind a duplicate definition in a separate translation unit. Then link *all* object files together (compiled with debugging symbols enabled). The linker will tell you in what file and on what line the duplicate is defined.

Comment: @n.m. You have understood my query exactly right. Your suggestion worked for my test c functions finding method. Let me apply this on project I am working on let you know the results.

Comment: @n.m you can post an answer on the suggestion you have made. This is the best one so far I have came across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try deliberately addind a duplicate definition in a separate translation unit. Then link *all* object files together (compiled with debugging symbols enabled). The linker will tell you in what file and on what line the duplicate is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `-E` switch ?

```
// a.h
int a() {
  return 1;
}
```

and then, we have

```
// main.c
#include "a.h"

int main() {
  return a();
}
```

and, with `-E` you can get

```
> gcc -E main.c
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 331 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "main.c" 2
# 1 "./a.h" 1
int a() {
  return 1;
}
# 2 "main.c" 2

int main() {
  return a();
}
```

now, let's say our source has another file

```
// b.h
float a() {
  return 1.0;
}
```

and `main.c` is slightly different

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main() {
  return a();
}
```

you will be able to see the last definition of function

```
gcc -c -E main.c
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 331 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "main.c" 2
# 1 "./a.h" 1
int a() {
  return 1;
}
# 2 "main.c" 2
# 1 "./b.h" 1
float a() {
  return 1.0;
}
# 3 "main.c" 2

int main() {
  return a();
}
```

But, I am not sure whether this is something you are looking for ;)

Hmm ... if you want to stop at certain point, maybe this one will help you:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main() {
  a();
  #error Quit!
  printfun("aaa");
}
```

and this way, compilation will fail a `#error`

```
> gcc -c  -Wfatal-errors main.c
In file included from main.c:2:
./b.h:1:7: fatal error: conflicting types for 'a'
float a() {
      ^
./a.h:1:5: note: previous definition is here
int a() {
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Or, you can simply introduce some sort of fake type

```
#include "a.h"

struct fake_type {
  int fake_component;
};

struct fake_type *a();

int main() {
  a();
}
```

and enforce the error

```
> gcc -c  -Wfatal-errors main.c
main.c:7:19: fatal error: conflicting types for 'a'
struct fake_type *a();
                  ^
./a.h:1:5: note: previous definition is here
int a() {
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: The -E option will do a preprocessing part of compilation process in gcc. That will print the entire code. What i am looking for is to get to line number, path and file name which has the definition of function by deliberately adding an error at the place where we are calling the function; which the compile points us to look in. I would edit my question with an example.